# What are the differences b/w Hashtable, Dictionary and KeyValuePair?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable, key-value

I use Dictionary in my code but my colleagues use Hashtable. MSDN says they work on Key Value pair &
examples of Hashtable and dictionary are same on MSDN.

Then how different are they from each other & which is the best of them or are they suited for difference occasions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Dictionary is preferred over hashtable in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-dictionary-is-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Hashtable` is an untyped associative container that uses `DictionaryEntry` class to return results of enumeration through its key-value pairs.

`Dictionary<K,T>` is a generic replacement of `Hashtable` that was introduced in C# 2.0. It uses `KeyValuePair<K,T>` generic objects to represent its key-value pairs.

The only place where you should see `Hashtable` these days is legacy code that must run on .NET 1.1, before generics have been introduced. It's been kept around for compatibility reasons, but you should prefer `Dictionary<K,T>` whenever you can.

Answer (score 22):

`KeyValuePair` is the unit of data stored in a `Hashtable` (or `Dictionary`).  They are not equivalent to each other.

A key value pair contains a single key and a single value.  A dictionary or hashtable contains a mapping of many keys to their associated values.

`KeyValuePair` is useful when you want to store two related pieces of information as a single unit, especially when one is related to the other in an identifying way (for instance 1234 => "David Smith"). They are also what you get back when you iterate a dictionary.  In .NET 4.0, these are really only meant for use internally in a Dictionary- the Tuple class has been introduced for general purpose use.

The difference between `Hashtable` and `Dictionary` is that `Hashtable` is not a generic class- both it's keys and values are of type `Object`.  `Dictionary` is generic, and should generally be used in favor of `Hashtable` in any new development.

Answer (score 7):

A dictionary is a typed hashtable. If you know the data type of the key and value, use a dictionary for performance reasons (avoid casting).

Answer (score 3):

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a type used by `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.   When you iterate over the items in a Dictionary, you get a series of `KeyValuePair` objects.

Here's some sample usage:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

dict.Add("Hello", 1);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in dict)
{
    string s = entry.Key;
    int i = entry.Value;

    // More logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One major difference is that `Hashtable` is thread-safe, while `Dictionary` is not.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) says:

> `Hashtable` is thread safe for use by multiple reader threads and a single writing thread. It is thread safe for multi-thread use when only one of the threads perform write (update) operations, which allows for lock-free reads provided that the writers are serialized to the `Hashtable`. To support multiple writers all operations on the `Hashtable` must be done through the wrapper returned by the `Synchronized` method, provided that there are no threads reading the Hashtable object.

Contrast this with the [`Dictionary` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> A `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

Comment: Isn't this just a "rehash" of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876656/difference-between-dictionary-and-hashtable  ??