# Dictionary or hashtable as a parameterized constructor in a class

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, constructor, hashtable

I am working on wpf application and i have to pass some global objects from one class to other, so i am declaring a parameterized construtor for the class,
my concern is which one would performance better as a parameter , dictionary or hashtable.
i read this post [Difference between Dictionary and Hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876656/difference-between-dictionary-and-hashtable) 
following code is using hashtable

```
      public partial class Sample: Window
        {
      Hashtable session = new Hashtable();

 string Path= string.Empty;
 string PathID= string.Empty;

           public Sample(Hashtable hashtable)
            {
                if (session != null)
                {
                    this.session = hashtable;
                    Path= session["Path"].ToString()
                    PathID= session["MainID"].ToString();
                }
                InitializeComponent();
            }
     private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
            }
    }
```

Comment: `Hashtable` is untyped, seems to me you want an `IDictionary<string, string>`, or better still, define a class that actually represents your settings.

Comment: Dictionary, in my experience, is faster, but read only... You can assign a dictionary, but then only read from it. If you want to edit data in it, you'll have to use a hash table.

Comment: @NewAmbition: Why is a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) read-only? Never was ...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper; Read-only as in you can only define it in the beginning, then read from it throughout the application. Dictionary's are meant for quickly finding data in it using wither a key or value. I've never been able to edit a single key/value after defining it. I may be horribly mistaken.

Comment: @NewAmbition: You can use methods such as [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) whenever you like on a dictionary, and you can also set or overwrite items by using the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, deleting and adding is different to editing an entry.

Comment: @NewAmbition: What do you mean by *editing an entry* then? Changing the value associated with a given key? You can use the indexer for that, as I said, or (for complex values) the respective members of the value.

Comment: @jodell:there are doing to be more than 2 item in hashtable,and i thing  hash table is going to be more suitable for my need , my only concern was the performance

Comment: @Buzz I've edited my answer to illustrate. If you are concerned about performance get explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't,

```
public Sample(string path, string mainId)
{
    this.Path = path;
    this.PathID = mainId;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Be simpler, faster and easier to read, bringing errors to compile time etc?

---

In the event that the values to be passed are too numerous,

```
class NumerousSettings
{
    public string Path {get; set;};
    public string MainId  {get; set;};
    ...
}

public Sample(NumerousSettings settings)
{
    if (settings == null)
    {
        throw new CallTheDefaultContructorException();
    }

    this.Path = settings.Path;
    this.PathID = settings.MainId;
    ...

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: i have shown objects for simplicity ,there are gonaa be more than 2 item in hashtable

Comment: @Buzz, Since you now what the settings will be you can declare a type for them. By using weaker typing or unecessary serialization you are saving up the pain for runtime. A defined compiled type is also faster, there is no lookup time.

Answer (score 1):

> i read this post [Difference between Dictionary and Hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876656/difference-between-dictionary-and-hashtable)

OK, well Marc's answer there seemed pretty clear...

"*If you are .NET 2.0 or above, you should prefer Dictionary (and the other generic collections)*

*A subtle but important difference is that Hashtable supports multiple reader threads with a single writer thread, while Dictionary offers no thread safety. If you need thread safety with a generic dictionary, you must implement your own synchronization or (in .NET 4.0) use ConcurrentDictionary.*"

If you have no need for thread safety then the Dictionary is the preferred approach for type safety and performance.