# Matching invariant strings with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I got collection of structures with string property. Given an array of strings I want to check if there is any structure which inner string matches some of them in the array. I did it in this way:

```
    struct S
    {
        public string s { get; set; }
    }

    private List<S> List = new List<S>(); // populated somewhere else

    public bool Check(params string[] arr)
    {
        return (from s1 in List
                select s1.s into s1
                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1)
                join s2 in arr on s1.ToLowerInvariant() equals s2.ToLowerInvariant() select s1).Any();
    }
```

Simply, I just want to achieve StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase. Is it a proper way to do so? Is it efficient?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `HashSet`, which should have a similar performance to the `Dictionary`:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(
     List.Select(x => x.s),
     StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

return arr.Any(set.Contains);
```

Comment: The nice bit here is that you're telling the hash which comparison to use, rather than converting every string.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do so is to create a dictionary based on the collection of structures you have.

```
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(item=>item.s.ToLowerInvariant(),item=>item);
```

Then you could loop through your array of strings (O(n)):

```
foreach(item in array)
{
    S value;
    // This is an O(1) operation.
    if(dictionary.TryGetValue(item.ToLowerInvariant(), out value)
    {
        // The TryGetValue returns true if the an item 
        // in the dictionary found with the specified key, item
        // in our case. Otherwise, it returns false.
    }
}
```

Comment: @greenshade Exactly ! However there is a subtle difference, which you should be aware of. Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876656/difference-between-dictionary-and-hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
class Program
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<MyStruct>();
        list.Add(new MyStruct { Data = "A" });
        list.Add(new MyStruct { Data = "B" });
        list.Add(new MyStruct { Data = "C" });


        var arr = new string[] { "a", "b" };

        var result = (from s in list
                      from a in arr
                      where s.Data.Equals(a, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                      select s).ToArray();
    }
}
```