# Elegant way to do Dictionary<Key, Collection<Value>>

Tags: c#, types

What is the best way to store a map of key object to a collection of value objects?
I could use

```
Dictionary<KeyType, Collection<ValueType>>
```

but that approach tends to involve a lot of housekeeping, and clutters up the code.

The Lookup type is almost the result I'm looking for, but it's immutable and has no constructor. I could create my own custom class, but it seems like it should exist in the framework *somewhere*.

Comment: Unfortunately .NET is somewhat limited when it comes to out-of-the-box collection types :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380595/multimap-in-c-3-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's about your best answer. It's pretty common to use `Dictionary<KeyType, ICollection<ValueType>>`. Using the `var` keyword to declare your local variables is the best way to tidy up.

Other than that, your only option is creating a `MultiDictionary<T,K>` type. You could also call it `Lookup` and put it in your own namespace?

Edit: Google says you should take a look at this for an existing implementation: [Multi-value Dictionary C# source code (.NET 3.5)](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2009/05/18/multi-value-dictionary-c-source-code-net-3-5.aspx). BSD2 license means you can use it for commercial apps with at attribution. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could also, as for tidying, alias the specific generic type:

```
using MultiDictionary = Dictionary<string, ICollection<int>>;
```

Then later:

```
var foo = new MultiDictionary();
```

Comment: The part I don't like about this is you can't do generic aliases, and it's hard to keep consistency across source files. Fortunately it doesn't break Find All References.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 3.5, there is `ILookup<Tkey,TValue>` and `Lookup<TKey,TValue>` that serves this purpose; however, the default implementation is immutable. I wrote a mutable variant for [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/); `EditableLookup<TKey,TValue>` - which does exactly what you want.