# Add items to a Dictionary<int, List<int>>

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

So I am looping through some objects and initializing a Dictionary> object.

So first I check if the key exists, if it does I will add to the List

If it doesn't, I will create a new key and new List

Is that the right logic?
I will have to do a:

```
new List<int>();
```

the first time I insert an item right?

i.e.:

```
if(myDic.ContainsKey(car.ID))
{
      myDic[car.ID].Add(car.MfgID);
}
else
{
   myDic.Add(car.ID, new List<int>);
   myDic[car.ID].Add(car.MfgID);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your approach works fine. It's a little inefficient as it requires two dictionary lookups (one for `Contains` and one for adding the item to the list). You can do it more efficiently using [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkw5c9ak(VS.85).aspx) method:

```
List<int> list;
if (!myDic.TryGetValue(car.ID, out list))
    myDic.Add(car.ID, list = new List<int>());
list.Add(car.MfgId);
```

It's more efficient to fill the list and add it to the dictionary in one go (if it's possible in your case, of course). In C# 3.0, there's a feature called *collection initializers* that makes it easy to fill a list if items are known at compile time:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 9, 8, 9, 1, 8, 1, 2 };
```

You might also consider using [something like this to map a key to multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380595/multimap-in-c-3-0/380601#380601).

Comment: Great, now you and Reed just need to combine both answers into one :)

Comment: Oh, and collection initializers might also be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Pavel: My answer eliminates the need for reordering mentioned in Reed's answer. It always does a single dictionary lookup.