# Run-length encoding of a given sorted string

Tags: c#, linq, run-length-encoding

> Write code for run -length encoding of a given string
>   Sample Input: aaaaaaaaaabcccccc
>   Output: a10bc6

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "aaaaaaaaaabcccccc";
    var qry = (from c in str
               group c by c into grp
               select new
               {
                   output = grp.Key.ToString() + grp.Count().ToString()
               });
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in qry)
    {
        sb.Append(item.output);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However it returns:

> a10b1c6

I want to remove the count for non-repeating char, here is "1" for letter 'b'.

Assume that it is a sorted string.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. What would you get with `aaaaaabccccccaaa`

Comment: @L.B,Sorry about it. I assume it is a sorted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version:

```
public static void Main()
{
   string str = "aaaaaaaaaabcccccc";
    var qry = (from c in str
               group c by c into grp
               let c = grp.Count()
               select grp.Key.ToString() + (c > 1 ? c.ToString() : ""));

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",qry));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You need to be careful with the bracket placement around the ternary expression, and then I used `string.Join` to avoid the mess with a `for each` loop and string builder.

Comment: It doesn't fully work. Input string "uuggikejfhhhhtttttii    hd" produces output "u2g2i3kejfh5t5 4d", the h in the end has gone missing... And if I add something in the beginning like "aaabbbdddduuggikejfhhhhtttttii    hd" then the output is "a3b3d5u2g2i3kejfh5t5 4", now the d at the end has gone missing too?

Comment: @CodeOrElse OP's question explicitly makes reference to `Assume that it is a sorted string.` which allows for a more simpler "group and count" strategy. I've addressed the more general case of RLE in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

add a ternary expression:

```
output = grp.Key + (grp.Count() > 1 ? grp.Count().ToString() : "")
```

Comment: Is  iterating on grp twice (``grp.Count()``)  smart ?

Comment: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'.

Comment: @Jonesy: Or the brackets are misplaced.

Comment: @Jonesy, please double check your code. I just copy and paste your code exactly.

Comment: @HuiZhao you're absolutely right, that was my bad, try it  now

Comment: @L.B `Count` is cached. Once it is executed it is stored since it's using a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` behind the scenes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am not so sure. using `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` doesn't make it *cached*, Can you post a link about it?

Comment: @L.B: not MSDN since it's an implementation detail, but a great alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362570/284240 (last sentence)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes a good reference, but still, better to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Although OP did mention as an afterthought that in his/her case his source string was sorted, in general, the input to [Run Length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) won't be sorted as will lose information and can't be decompressed. Here's a take on the more general case of unsorted:

```
  string str = "aaaaaaaabccccccaadddddaaa"; // a8bc6a2d5a3

  // Zip the string with itself, offset by 1 character. 
  // Duplicate the last char to make strings equal length
  var pairs = str
    .Zip((str + str.Last()).Skip(1),
         (prev, current) => new { prev, current });

  // Retain a horrid mutable sequence which tracks consecutive characters
  var sequence = 0;
  var grps = pairs.GroupBy(p => 
    new { Ch = p.prev, 
          Sequence = p.current == p.prev
          ? sequence 
          : sequence++});

  // Join this together, using the other solutions to drop the count from single chars
  var rle = String.Join("", 
    grps.Select(g => g.Count() > 1
        ? g.Key.Ch.ToString() + g.Count().ToString() 
        : g.Key.Ch.ToString()));
  Console.WriteLine(rle);
```

**Edit**
I guess the number comments indicate some violation of the [POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) which require explanation:

- The string is `Zip`ped with itself offset by one (`Skip`), in order to detect the boundaries of consecutive characters
- Since `Zip` stops on the shortest enumeration, the last character is repeated on the shortest string to handle the final character in the string.
- Unlike the 'sorted' RLE input string in the other answers, the Grouping key is done by the combination of character and a 'are the characters adjacent?' sequencer.
- This sequence is rather horridly incremented within a conditional in the projection lambda of the `GroupBy`
- @Jonesy's / @Tim's conditional join is used within a `String.Join` to reassemble the final encoded string.

Comment: The code works. If you could explain a little bit your algorithm, it would be great. Why did you create a new string which had same length and offset by 1?

Comment: You are right - there were many astonishing things in the code - I've updated with an explanation included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator for the core issue. Another approach is to use a `Lookup` which is similar to a dictionary and `String.Concat`:

```
var charLook = input.ToLookup(c => c);
string result = string.Concat(charLook
    .Select(g => string.Format("{0}{1}", g.Key, g.Count()==1 ? "" : g.Count().ToString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below, it might help:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string x = "aaaaaaaaaabcccccc";
char[] c = x.ToCharArray();
char[] t = c.Distinct().ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
{
   int count = 0;

   for (int j = 1; j < c.Length; j++)
   {  
       if (t[i] == c[j - 1])
       {
          count++;
       }
   }

   if (count > 1)
   {
       sb.Append(t[i] + count.ToString());
   }
   else
   {
       sb.Append(t[i]);
   }

}
Console.Write(sb);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a short RegEx solution. Posting here to share, along with a [great RegEx cheat sheet](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet).

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\D)\1+", c => c.Length.ToString() + c.Value[0]);
```

Comment: And found a huge list of solutions at https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#C.23