# Replace consecutive numbers with mathematical form

Tags: algorithm, compression, number-formatting

I am working on **compression algorithm** for which I want to **replace** all **consecutive number** with its **mathematical** form which is not logical **mathematically** but my algorithm will know and convert it to original form.
Suppose I have string:

```cs
string input = "732183900000000000002389288888888888888";
```

Did you see it have **0000000000** and **8888888888888** are major **consecutive duplicates**.
And now I want to convert those to:

```cs
//convert 000000000 to 0*9. Means 9 times 0.
//convert 888888888 to 8*9. Means 8 times 0.
string output = "7321839" +
                "0*13"    +
                "23892"   +
                "8*14";
//or
string output = "7321839-0*13-23892-8*14";
```

**Points to consider:**
Any **language** that works on **windows** will be **accepted**. For me main thing is **algorithm**.
Please keep **performance** in mind as it would be used for **big** files.

Comment: What have you tried? How has it failed to meet your requirements? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Regarding your question, it seems like a straightforward linear scan through the input string maintaining a count of how many times in a row it's seen the current digit would be fine, but you'd still have decide how many times a digit has to repeat before you replace its occurrences with the shorthand in the output.

Comment: Thanks. I tried regex & other SO answers but without a luck. I believe it can be archived using c# regex.

Comment: google RLE (Run  Length Encoding)

Comment: @Spektre Wow. I was not aware of RLE but my algorithm do same thing. You can answer and I will tick. I found many things. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27573642/14784394 , https://gist.github.com/sujaykundu777/9ee3328bf15fcc2b41a3576cf08b996c

Comment: With [C# regex](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z7xXL7).

Comment: @AlexHales that is too trivial to be an answer ... RLE is pretty common .. for example PCX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex might be a bit convoluted for this given the rules for dashes (although not impossible by any means),

Seemingly, you want the following

1. Groups of the same number greater than the count of 1
2. No prefix dash
3. No suffix dash
4. No double dashes (speculative)

Here is a fairly efficient C# *O(n)* implementation with `StringBuilder`, which inurn should allow you to work with exceedingly large strings with minimal allocations

**Given**

```cs
public static string Shorten(string value)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
    int i, last;
    var isLastGroup = false;

    void Write()
    {
        var isGroup = i - last > 1;
        var getDash = last == 0 || isLastGroup ? "" : "-";
        sb.Append(isGroup ? $"{getDash}{value[last]}*{i - last}{(i != value.Length ? "-" : "")}" : value[last].ToString());
        isLastGroup = isGroup;
        last = i;
    }

    for (i = 0, last = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        if (value[last] != value[i])
            Write();

    Write();

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Tests**

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Shorten("1"));
Console.WriteLine(Shorten("111"));
Console.WriteLine(Shorten("1112"));
Console.WriteLine(Shorten("1222"));
Console.WriteLine(Shorten("12233344445555512345"));
```

**Results**

> 1
> 1*3
>
> 1*3-2
> 1-2*3
>
> 1-2*2-3*3-4*4-5*5-12345

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Woxk1J)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest this is as simple as it gets:

- Parse through the string one character at a time.
- Check if the previous character is the same as the current one.
- If it is same then increment a counter variable or else reset it to 0.
- If the counter value is greater than one when we reset the counter to 0 then add * to the result.

Comment: You probably would set the threshold higher than 2 instances in a row. It wouldn't make a lot of sense to "compress" `55` to `-5*2-`, for instance. But the basic idea seems sound.

Comment: @NathanPierson Right. short strings should not be compressed. But long should be.

Comment: @saurav-chanda Thanks. code implementation would be appreciated. Specially regex.