# Combine 2 linq operations

Tags: c#, linq

Greetings I've got a logic question I have got 2 procedures

First is linq that looks like:

```
 _sharedDocumentsAttachments = SourceDocumentAttachmentMeta
 .Where(sDoc => TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta.Any(tDoc => tDoc.DocumentBridgeId == sDoc.DocumentId)).ToList();
```

Where

```
List<DocumentAttachment> _sharedDocumentsAttachments;
```

And

```
SharedDocumnentAttachmentConnector = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (DocumentAttachment document in _sharedDocumentsAttachments)
{
    foreach (DocumentAttachment tDoc in TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta.Where(tDoc => document.DocumentId == tDoc.DocumentBridgeId))
    {
         SharedDocumnentAttachmentConnector.Add(document.DocumentId, tDoc.DocumentId);
    }
}
```

And I was wondering if I can attach second procedure to the first one somehow, as basically the are doing same compare but adding values to 2 different collections?

I was experimenting with for each but it wont work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this: join the two collections and then specify how to convert to dictionary

```
_sharedDocumentsAttachments.Join(TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta,
                                 document => document.DocumentId,
                                 tDoc => tDoc.targetDocument,
                                 (document, tDoc) => new 
                                 { 
                                     Key = document.DocumentId, 
                                     Value = tDoc.DocumentId 
                                 })
                            .ToDictionary(item => item.Key,
                                          item => item.Value);
```

Take note that if the join will result with 2 "records" for the same document.DocumentId it will throw a `ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added`.

If that might happen then think of:

1. Saving it as a `LookUp`
2. Saving it as a `Dictionary<int,IEnumerable<int>>`

For differences between the two [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362490/difference-between-lookup-and-dictionaryof-list)