# Getting all duplicates form a List<T> object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have some LINQ code (unfortunatley not to hand!) to get duplicates from a list object. However, the duplicates in the original list are like so:

```
Item A
Item A
Item A
Item B
Item B
Item C
Item C
Item C
Item C

etc...
```

What I'd like to do is extend the LINQ query to get all of those duplicate instances, not just the first instance in a duplicate pair, or trio.

What would be an ideal query to get this?

Comment: Is `GroupBy` not sufficient?

Comment: The given answers are correct, but I note that you can be considerably more memory-efficient if you know that the list containing duplicates is sorted so that all the duplicates are together -- as is the case in your sample list. Do you in fact know ahead of time that the list will be in this form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group on the property and get the groups that has more than one item. Example:

```
List<IGrouping<Item>> duplicates =
  items.GroupBy(i => i.Name).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

Now each group contains all the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. The List is actually storing just string objects, so would I just change i.Name to i? Thanks

Comment: @dotnetdev: Yes, you would. However, if there is no more information that the string, then there's little point in getting all the duplicate items as they will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.90).aspx) method to do the same:

```
var duplicates= Items.ToLookup(s => s).Where(g=>g.Count()>1);
```

If you want to see the differences between the `GroupBy` and `ToLookup`, I suggest you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739462/lookup-vs-groupby) to see the answer of @JonSkeet