# C# split list into two lists using bool function

Tags: c#, list, filter

Say I have a `List<string> listOfStrings` and I want to divide this list into two lists based on some predicate. E.g., the first list should contain all strings that start with a letter, and second is a list of strings that don't.

Now I would do this like this:

```
var firstList = listOfStrings.Where(str => predicate(str));
var secondList = listOfStrings.Where(str => !predicate(str));
```

Is there a better way of doing this in one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Linq's `GroupBy()`:

```
var splitted = listOfStrings.GroupBy(s => Char.IsLetter(s[0]));
```

And with your `predicate`, it would be:

```
Func<string, bool> predicate;

var splitted = listOfStrings.GroupBy(predicate);
```

**Usage:**

The easiest way would be to convert the grouped data into a `Dictionary<bool, IEnumerable<string>>`, when the key is a `bool` that denotes whether the items in it start with a letter:

```
var splitted = list.GroupBy(x => Char.IsLetter(x[0]))
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, z => z.ToArray());  

var startWithLetter = splitted[true];
var dontStartWithLetter = splitted[false];
```

Of course, there are many ways to massage the data into your desired structure, but the above is pretty concise in my opinion.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks, but for completeness, can you please add an example of how to retrieve both lists out of `splitted`?

Comment: @eddyP23, Done.

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin has [partition](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) function ([sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/d34c23914acc9fc6a147ffd6366cb89bd594d9c3/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L3036)). C# version:

```
var (first, second) = list.Partition(x => x.IsTrue);
```

Extension:

```
public static (IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second) Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var lookup = list.ToLookup(predicate);
    return (lookup[true], lookup[false]);
}
```

Could be more convenient to return `List<T>`, or to use GroupBy or something else, depending on use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'GroupBy' or 'ToLookup', based on what you will be doing with the results.
Check also [lookup vs. groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739462/lookup-vs-groupby/13739527)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<string, bool> startsWithA = s => s[0] == 'a';

        List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>()
        {
            "abc",
            "acb",
            "bac",
            "bca",
            "cab",
            "cba"
        };

        Dictionary<bool, List<string>> dictionaryOfListsOfStrings = listOfStrings.GroupBy(startsWithA).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
    }
}
```