# Dictionary with Exact Same Keys and Values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, dictionary

I need something like a Dictionary or a SortedList but i keep getting exceptions thrown when it receives two things that are the same... Is there another way around this?

Thanks

Comment: You could download PRISM and use the ListDictionay class.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). You can simulate one with a `Dictionary<Key, List<Value>>`. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380595/multimap-in-net), it has some multimap implementations.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you're using

```
dictionary.Add(key, value);
```

If you're happy just *replacing* the existing key/value pair, then just use the indexer:

```
dictionary[key] = value;
```

If you want to have multiple values for the same key, see the other answers :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you just reminded me of my favorite Jon Skeet Fact: If you have $5 and Jon Skeet has $5, Jon Skeet has more money than you. Lol. :)... +1

Comment: I'm actually using it to store info about emails. I'm using the Key to store the senders email, and the value is holding the subject of the email

Comment: @j-t-s: So what's the actual *meaning* of there being more than one email from a particular user? Do you need to store all the subjects, or just the latest one?

Comment: well, when i check for email, it will download all emails from the server and place the sender and subject into a Dictionary. But quite often my investor sends tonnes of emails everyday with the exact same subject. I think I've tried every type of List available but they all seem to be the same. I am checking out the ones provided in these answers but I was kinda hoping for something kinda simple

Answer (score 0):

The key in a dictionary or a sorted list the key should be unique: that's the purpose of hashtables. You could use `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` or `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]` instead but of course you won't be able to locate a value by key as you may have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Both a dictionary and a sortedlist are keyed, meaning that the keys must be unique.

You could check before you add the item, e.g. `dic.ContainsKey(key)` or `list.Contains(item)` before adding.

If you would like to be able to add multiple values for a single key you can use a `NameValueCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking for is a dictionary where the value is the same as the key, then there's a generic collection type named 'HashSet' in the System.Collections.Generic namespace which looks like it serves that purpose.

If you're just asking about an exception generated when adding to your dictionary, I think Jon Skeet is probably right on what is probably your issue.

HashSet:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx