# Is there a generic collection with a key/value pair where key can occur more than once?

Tags: .net, dictionary, generic-collections

I want to use a generic collection like `Dictionary`, but `Dictionary` requires that every key be unique. I have multiple values for the same "key", so I need a generic collection that will allow for that.

I realize that this makes the *key* no longer really a key, but I don't know what else to call it.

Comment: For anyone who cares, I ended up just including a reference to the value I wanted to track inside the value object. Then I just used a List<mySpecialSuperDuperObject> and was able to access the value through the propery in my object. Thanks to everyone who answered. I will use this information for use in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate keys in .NET dictionaries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Several options for you to consider:

- use a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` — keep a *list* of values for each key, **not preventing duplicate** values for the same key (i.e. duplicate pairs);
- use a `Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>` — keep a *set* of value for each key, **preventing duplicate values** for the same key;
- use a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` — keep a list of pair, **not preventing duplicate** values for the same key.

Note that in the latter case `KeyValuePair` is a `struct`, not a `class`, hence that implies a bit different handling.

The right option depends on your actual use case.

Comment: I think your second suggestion makes the most sense to me. It would allow me to iterate over the keys and get the values, but wouldn't require the keys to be unique across the collection. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also note that it won't prevent from storing duplicate pairs. If that's a concern, the first approach with a `HashSet` would be better. (Edited my answer to cover that.)

Answer (score 8):

In .NET 3.5 and above, that is `ILookup<TKey,TValue>`. Unfortunately the only *provided* implementation is the immutable `Lookup<TKey,TValue>`, however it is easy to re-implement. An `EditableLookup<TKey,TValue>` is included in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

With an `ILookup<TKey,TValue>`, the `TKey` indexer returns an `IEnumerable<TValue>` (even if there were no matches for that key), so typical usage is:

```
foreach(var value in lookup[key])
    DoSomethingWith(value);
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++, such a collection is called a multimap. A quick search for that term revealed this related question:

> [multimap in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380595/multimap-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>` and do the manual work yourself, but there is no "multi-dictionary" collection by default.

That said, if you have an IEnumerable you can convert it to a lookup which is like what you described, but can't be constructed by itself (have to call ToLookup() to create from enumeration).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Dictionary<KeyType,List<ValueType>>`.

You can create a custom dictionary which wraps this dictionary to handle all the required logic upon adding and removing.

Comment: Dictionary will require _KeyType_ to be unique. I want to use the same value for the key more than once.

Answer (score 0):

For your value, you could store a list of whatever it is you want to hold.