# namevaluecollection vs lookup

Tags: .net, lookup, namevaluecollection

I need to represent some data that has a key and one or more values, seems there is a namevaluecollection or a lookup.

From what I can tell the main difference between the two is that lookup is immutable, is there any other significant differences in the two I should be aware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multimap in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380595/multimap-in-net)

Comment: similar but doesnt really talk much about namevaluecollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`NameValueCollection` and `ILookup` are different in several ways.**

First, NameValueCollection is a map from string -> string - each key can only have one value, and both the key and the value must be strings. This doesn't sound like it meets your requirement:

> I need to represent some data that has a key and one or more values

Second, `ILookup` is essentially a generic multimap - it maps a key to a set of one or more values - and both the key and values can be of any type. `ILookup<,>` is immutable, as you mention, but it's also not directly constructable. The only way to get an instance is to use the `Enumerable.ToLookup()` method. This requires that all of the data must be available at once - you can't build the multimap over time.

If what you really need is a mutable multimap, you should look at either the `EditableLookup<,>` in [MiscUtil](http://www.pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/),  your wrap a `Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>` in your own type.

Comment: `NameValueCollection` *can* have multiple values for a single key.