# How to get value by the help of key from KeyValuePair in C#

Tags: c#, .net, key-value, generic-collections

```
static private List<KeyValuePair<string, Employee>> employeesList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Employee>>();
```

This is my generic `KeyValuePair` List that stores employee objects with `employeeid` as key.
How to get value i.e `Employee` object with the help of the string key.

Comment: Why don't you use `Dictionary<string, Employee>`?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `Dictionary`? Otherwise you’ll need to search through the whole list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414429/c-sharp-get-keys-and-values-from-listkeyvaluepairstring-string

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

Employee employee = employeesList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == employeeId).Value;
```

You'd be better off using a Dictionary though. That way you could look up the Id directly rather than iterating the list.

```
Employee employee = employoeesDictionary[employeeId];
```

Comment: `?` operator cannot be applied to `KeyValuePair<string, int>`

Comment: True. forgot KeyValuePair was a struct. Modded answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var employee = employeesList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "").Value;
```

you can not use `?` operator.