# Building a collection of objects retrievable via tags

Tags: c#, collections

I need a collection that can store and retrieve objects with multiple, potentially shared tags. I need to be able to store one object with multiple tags, and retrieve all objects that have one or more tags.

My first idea was for the collection to store an array of objects, and a `Dictionary<string, Hashset<int>>` where the key is the tag and the value is the indexes that tag applies to.

- For multiple tags, get the intersection of the index collections
- To remove a tag from an object, remove that index from the collection

however, if an object is removed from the collection, all the indexes after that point are now incorrect.

Am I heading in the right direction? Is there an existing implementation of this that I'm unaware of, or a standard approach to collections that would help here?

Comment: IS this in memory or database

Comment: This is in memory I guess?

Comment: _store and retrieve_ Define!

Comment: @TaW Store: Put an object into the collection with associated tags.
Retrieve: Give a tag to the collection and get all of the objects with that tag.
I'm not sure what you're asking for...

Comment: Usually store/retrieve means some way to persist data e.g. in  a DBMS, a file etc..

Comment: And why all indexes are incorrect after you remove an object?

Comment: @Evk I have indexes 0-5. I remove the object at index 2, and 3-5 shifts down. Now things pointing to 5 should point to 4, etc.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. I assumed `HashSet<int>` contains some unique key of the object, not just plain array index of it. But even without unique key - you can just store object itself in that `HashSet`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/380601/4370629

Comment: @Spotted That seems like more of a shortcut for a `Dictionary<T1, List<T2>>` than a many-to-many tag system.

Comment: Have you considered using a (in-memory) database ? (which handles well many-to-many relationships)

Answer (score 2):

**Given**

```
public class Something
{
   public HashSet<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<Something>
               {
                  new Something()
                     {
                        Tags = new HashSet<string>() { "tag1", "tag2" }
                     },
                  new Something()
                     {
                        Tags = new HashSet<string>() { "tag3", "tag4" }
                     }
               };

var searchList = new List<string> { "tag1", "tag4"};

var result = list.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => searchList.Contains(y)));
```

Fairly standard in memory approach

If you wanted it more typed, use enums (if you don't need them dynamic)

Comment: BTW OP approach isn't wrong: your approach doesn't index tags but you rely on search which is slower than using hashed collections...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer completely agree, how ever its simple easy and maintainable

Comment: OP approach is easy and maintainable as well :D

Comment: This would work, certainly, but I was hoping for something a bit more contained that didn't rely on me retyping or copying the LINQ to access it every time. It also seems messy/rigid to use a wrapper class like that, though that might just be my preference. Either way, I'd definitely modify it to hold a generic type at least.

Answer (score 1):

You've headed in the right direction. I would say that you should *cache* common intersections in other `HashSet<T>` instances to even speed up and simplifiy things more.

> however, if an object is removed from the collection, all the indexes
>   after that point are now incorrect.

Although you can build an inverse dictionary `Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>` in order to remove a given object from the tag index to avoid iterating the entire index when some object is removed:

```
var tags = objectTagMap[394]

foreach(var tag in tags) 
   tagObjectMap[tag].Remove(394)
```

Anyway, if you're thinking about an in-memory index, why don't you use *Redis*? Redis provides you both hashes (dictionaries), sets and sorted sets (and some other data structures).

This is a very very simplified sample of how you would build the same strategy in Redis:

```
# Store objects as key-value pairs
set object:1 { "id": 1 }
set object:2 { "id": 2 }
set object:3 { "id": 3 }

// sadd (set add) to build the tag index
sadd tagA 1 2
sadd tagB 3

// sunion to get object ids from two or more tags
sunion tagA tagB

// mget (multiple get) to get object data from the result 
// of sunion concatenating "object:" with each object id
// This is a simple example. In a real world system you would use
// SCAN to avoid bottlenecks and being able to leverage paging.
mget object:1 object:2 object:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
Dictionary<List<string>, HashSet<int>> taggedDict = new Dictionary<List<string>, HashSet<int>>();
var searchList = new List<string> { "tag1", "tag4" };
var keys = taggedDict.Keys.Where(x => x.Any(y => searchList.Contains(y)));
```

Comment: This would probably work, but I'd use a hashset for both the key and value. That said, it suffers from the same issue as TheGeneral's answer with regards to LINQ - it's unwieldy, especially having to retype or copy + paste the same line each time I want to access a value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best way, but the way I'm using for now until it becomes a problem is simply a collection consisting of two dictionaries; `Dictionary<string, Hashset<T>>` to get objects with a tag, and `Dictionary<T, Hashset<string>>` to get the tags on an object. It's simple and functional, and should suffice for smaller collections.