# Check if dictionary with objects for it's values contains two objects with same property

Tags: c#, linq

**My question is not duplicate as the one that you have marked is searching `List` and I am trying to search `Dictionary`.**

I have a `Dictionary<string, Player>`.

`Player` is an object with the properties `GameID, Index` and more. My dictionary key is player's `index`. I want to check if dictionary contains two `Player`s with same `GameID` (the `index` will be different for those). One way of doing this is iterating with `foreach` over dictionary values and use an variable which would be incremented every time it encounters certain `GameID`. But I was wondering if there is a way to do this by using `linq`? If there is, that solution would probably be better.

Comment: Looping over a list or a dictionary, what's the big difference?

Comment: Specifically: in this part of code `.Values`. But I got used to people who are prone to hating and giving minuses here on stackoverflow just because they understand something better then the others

Comment: Just because you are using different container class does not make your question unique. Even w/o `Values` property, `Dictionary<string, Player>` is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Player>>`. And LINQ to Objects operate on `IEnumerable<T>` regardless of what class is implementing it (array, list, dictionary, whatever). So it really doesn't matter what is the actual collection type. The only important is the *element type*. Take the accepted answer from the duplicate question, replace `lstNames.GroupBy(n => n)` with `dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value.GameID)` and there you go.

Comment: @IvanStoev If there are people ready to help (and there are at least 3 of them here, based on answers) why do you have to point out it's a duplicate? You don't want to help? No problem, nobody forces you to, just move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ's `GroupBy` and then filter groups larger than one:

```
var result = dict.Values
             .GroupBy(x => x.GameID)
             .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
             .Select(g => g.First()); // Take one of the duplicates
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iz7GpT)

---

If you know the GameID to look for you can just use

```
var gameID = 1
var isDuplicate = dict.Values
                  .Where(x => x.GameID == gameID)
                  .Count() > 1;
```

Comment: Actually, at the moment of search I know exactly which `GameID` I am looking for, so I guess there should be another `WHERE` with condition `x.GameID == 1` for example? I am not sure how it should be written using `linq`.

Comment: @niksrb see my edit

Comment: Yes, trying it now in my code, will report soon

Comment: Why do we need to group ALL the data if we just want to find out whether there are  duplicates or not ? Imagine that there are 1 000 000 records and duplicated records are records on position 1 and 10... This solution will group the whole 1M records

Comment: @Fabjan You dont know where the duplicates are... They could be 1 and 999999. As I understood, he wants to know *which* are the duplicates, not whether there are any.

Comment: @Adrian How does that justify creation of up to 1 000 000 `IGroupping`s that OP doesn't need ? No the OP want's to know whether there *are* duplicates or not.

Comment: @Fabjan Thats why he asked for a solution that explicitly queries a certian GroupID? I guess not. Youre not even reading the comments

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries, differently than Lists, provide a constant complexity to access one of its entries.

The purpose of a `Dictionary` is to map a Key -> Value relation where keys are unique. By using a generic index as Key, there is no advantage over a `List<Player>`.

Therefore, rather than answering an inefficiently formulated problem, I will provide a more efficient solution reformulating the original question.

You can find an implementation of a Multimap (dictionary with multiple keys) where you can represent a `GameID-> Index` relationship and count occurrences, here: 
[multimap in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380595/multimap-in-net)

Compared to the (currently) accepted answer, which has linear time complexity ( O(N) ) and grows worse and worse for larger Dictionaries or Lists, even with the optimizations within IQueryable in Linq, this provides a constant complexity.

Comment: Will try that right away. Just one note, keys in my dictionary ARE unique, not generic

Comment: @niksrb I edited, sharing some insight

Comment: This really is more efficient solution. I will have it in mind next time I face similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

suppose that we have these records:

```
    Dictionary<string, Player> myDic = new Dictionary<string, Player>();
    Player p1 = new Player() { GameID = 1, Index = "a" };
    Player p2 = new Player() { GameID = 2, Index = "b" };
    Player p3 = new Player() { GameID = 1, Index = "c" };
    Player p4 = new Player() { GameID = 3, Index = "d" };
    myDic.Add(p1.Index, p1);
    myDic.Add(p2.Index, p2);
    myDic.Add(p3.Index, p3);
    myDic.Add(p4.Index, p4);
```

You can try this:

```
 var duplicates = myDic.Values
                .GroupBy(x => x.GameID)
                .SelectMany(p =>
                    p.Select((j, i) => new { j.Index, j.GameID, rn = i + 1 }))
                .Where(x => x.rn > 1).ToList();

            foreach (var dups in duplicates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"record with GameId: {dups.GameID} at Index: {dups.Index} is duplicate!");
            }
```